# jQuery: añadir/quitar clase procedente de librería externa ("CSShake")

Tags: jquery, css

He encontrado una librería CSS llamada CSShake que permite "agitar" los elementos HTML:

https://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/

Se utiliza de manera análoga a como se hace, por ejemplo, con Bootstrap (https://elrumordelaluz.github.io/csshake/#how-to); en el caso de la web que estoy creando:

```
<head>

    <title>50 años de Era Pop</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">

    <link href="css/estilos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

...

</head>
```

Bien, en mi web tengo listas de canciones de la siguiente manera, un top 15 por década:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código HTML es el siguiente, dentro de un bucle `while` tras la pertinente llamada a mi BD MySQL:

```
<div class="row mt-3"> <!-- Lista -->

    <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2"> <!-- Portada -->
        <?php echo '<img src="imagenes/'.$decada.'/'.$ano.'/'.$nombre_foto.'.jpg" width="50" height="50">'; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col ml-3"> <!-- Texto -->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span class="numero-decada">'.$count.'</span>'; ?> </div> <!-- Clasificación -->

            <div class="col informacion"> <!-- Información -->
                <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos"><span class="titulos cancion">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span> de&nbsp<span class="autor-decada">'.$nombre_autor.'</span>&nbsp'.$ano_disco.'</div>'; ?></div>
                <div class="row "><?php echo '<span id="votos">'.$votos_facebook.'&nbsp</span>'; if($votos_facebook == 1) echo 'voto'; else echo 'votos'; ?></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Haciendo uso de una clase de CSShake llamada `shake-slow`, quiero que al pasar el ratón por el título de la canción, el número se agite; para ello he escrito el siguiente script con JQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.cancion').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('.informacion').prev().find('span').addClass('shake-slow');
    });

    $('.cancion').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('.informacion').prev().find('span').removeClass('shake-slow');
    });
});
```

Pero no ocurre nada. La sintaxis es correcta -creo- porque si en vez de usar `shake-slow` utilizo una clase cualquiera de mi hoja de estilos CSS propia hay reacción.

Suponía que una librería externa, tipo Bootstrap o ésta llamada CSShake, funciona de manera análoga a una hoja de estilos propia que tengas en tu disco duro; ¿no es así?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Comenta el evento de escucha del `mouseleave` e inspecciona el elemento para uqe revises si realmente esta dandole esa clase al elemento que deseas. Si sucede asi entonces es posible que la clase no se llame asi o no este leyendo correctamente de tu archivo de css

Comment: Sigue sin ocurrir nada. El asunto es que lee el archivo y el nombre de la clase es correcto porque si la aplico tal cual a un elemento cualquiera, al pasar el ratón por encima de él, vibra (que es el objetivo básico de la librería).

Comment: Quire decir que si lo haces manual desde el inicio si funciona?

Comment: Pero fijate estuve mirando la pagina de esa libreria y al ponerle esa clase a un elemento de tu pagina lo que hace es ke cuando pases el mouse sobre el se mueva a excepcion que lo pongas ke este naimado indefinidamente. Eso quiere decir que si kieres probar debes comentar el mouseleave y cuando tu mouse entre en el elemento `cancion` pasale el mouse a los numeros a ver si se anima. Pk puede que se kite la clase antes de que te des cuenta de ke la animacion sucede con tu codigo viejo del mouseleave. Y cuando digo los numeros me refiero a los que corresponden a la misma cancion

Comment: Me refiero a que si añado esa clase a un elemento HTML cualquiera de la forma class="shake-slow", ese elemento vibra al pasar el ratón por encima de él y deja de vibrar cuando retiras el puntero. Es como funciona la librería, pero no sé si además es factible manipularla vía JQuery (esperaba que sí).

Comment: Has lo que te puse encima sino voy a tener que crear un fiddle para que veas que funciona

Comment: Mira como funciona en este fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w7kuzm89/

Comment: Vale, al comentar el mouseleave, pasar el ratón por el título y a continuación por el número, entonces vibra. Pero, claro, eso no era lo que pretendía...

Comment: El problema tuyo radica en que el mouse_enter de tus numeros es el mouse_leave del elemento canción. Es decir el uno reescribe al otro. Cuando entras con el mouse en el elemento del numero ya este no tiene la clase shake-slow pk se ejecuto el mouse-leave del elemento cancion. Me hice entender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la clase `".shake-slow"` y sus parecidas funcionan con `:hover`, entonces como tu aplicas la clase haciendo `:hover` desde otro contenedor solamente podrías ver la animación si hicieras `:hover` primero en el contenedor con la clase `".cancion"` y luego sobre la que tenga la clase `".shake-slow"` pero como a la vez cada vez que el mouse deja al contenedor con la clase `".canción"` está quitando la clase `".shake-slow"` entonces nunca podrías visualizar la animación... ahora puedes añadir una clase más llamada `".shake-constant"` que no necesita de `:hover` para hacer la animación de esta manera:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".cancion").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest(".informacion")
      .prev()
      .find("span")
      .addClass("shake-slow shake-constant");
  });

  $(".cancion").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this)
      .closest(".informacion")
      .prev()
      .find("span")
      .removeClass("shake-slow shake-constant");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">
<div class="row mt-3">    
    <div class="col ml-3">   
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mr-3">
                <span class="numero-decada">11</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col informacion">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="puntos">
                        <span class="titulos cancion">$titulo_cancion</span>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando te sucedan cosas similares a esta, te propongo realizar lo que he hecho yo.

Antes de nada, he visto que utilizas Jquery, ¿Porque no aprovecharlo?

1º Realizo un mouseeenter o el evento que quiero capturar, y realizo un "console.log()" simple del evento a capturar, y ver si funciona.

```
$('.cancion').mouseenter(function (event) {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Una vez confirmas que esa parte del código funciona, continua:

2º Busca el elemento en el evento, ya que lo has capturado.

```
$('.cancion').mouseenter(function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
});
```

3º Apoyate de Jquery que tienes implementado para, con ese elemento capturado desde el evento, lo "capturas o mas bien, tratas" con Jquery para simplificar todo.

```
$('.cancion').mouseenter(function (event) {
    const myElementToChange = event.target;
    $(myElementToChange).addClass('shake-slow');
});

$('.cancion').mouseenter(function (event) {
    const myElementToChange = event.target;
    $(myElementToChange).removeClass('shake-slow');
});
```

Hasta aquí, ya todo funciona. Sin embargo te voy a recomendar unos pasos extra que no te vendrán mal notar la diferencia.

4º Dado que utilizas Jquery, existen mejores formas de realizar esto, mas corto, apoyándote en métodos como "toggleClass", lo que hace basicamente es quitar o poner la clase según si existe o no. A su vez, a no ser que estrictamente necesites ese "mouseenter y mouseleave", puedes hacer uso de la siguiente forma:

```
$(".cancion").hover(function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass( "shake-slow" );
});
```

Como ves, queda bastante mas reducido gracias al potencial que ofrece Jquery. Dejo abajo del todo el ejemplo funcional.

---

También puede ser presentada de esta forma para controlar distintas acciones por separado

```
$(".cancion").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("shake-slow");
    // Entra el mouse
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("shake-slow");
    // Sale el mouse
  }
);
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cancion").hover(function(){
      $( this ).toggleClass( "shake-slow" );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="row mt-3"> <!-- Lista -->

    <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2"> <!-- Portada -->
        <img src="" width="50" height="50">
    </div>

    <div class="col ml-3"> <!-- Texto -->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="mr-3"><span class="numero-decada">numero</span></div> <!-- Clasificación -->

            <div class="col informacion"> <!-- Información -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="puntos">
                        <span class="titulos cancion">titulo cancion</span>
                        de&nbsp<span class="autor-decada">nombre autor</span>
                        año disco
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="row ">
                <span id="votos">votos facebook</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda :)

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con lo siguiente:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.cancion').mouseenter(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('.informacion').prev().find('span').addClass('shake-slow shake-constant');
    });

    $('.cancion').mouseleave(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('.informacion').prev().find('span').removeClass('shake-slow shake-constant');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sí, gracias, Dariel, es la solución que me ha proporcionado Christian unos mensajes más arriba.

Comment: Si ya despues que la habia publicado fue ke revise y vi que tenias una respuesta marcada ya jeje